# What non-daily dungeon awards the highest Gil/Stamina?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

At this point, the main constraint on building up my characters is Gil. I have a bunch of stuff I want to combine from 4+ to 5++, and even 5+ to 6++. I'm talking about a tab of *millions* of gil sitting in my inventory waiting to be spent on upgrades.

Now, obviously, the daily dungeon on Wednesday and Saturday is the *best* way to get lots of gil. I can clear half a million over the course of a day by checking in on coffee breaks, etc.

However, some days, like today, there's nothing else for me to really focus on; I'm mostly set for orbs - the ones I need, I can't get through todays daily. I've cleared and mastered all the elites. So mostly, I just want to find more gil. My first instinct is that the best bet is **FF VI: Mobliz Elite**. It has only one stage, a boss fight (that's fairly easy if I bring Terra with Biora) that costs 16 Stamina, and awards 12,000 gil for completion. That's an average of 750 Gil/Stam, ignoring  any chance of a drop.

But I haven't done any sort of analysis across stages. Which dungeon really is the best buck for my bang?

Answer (score 1):

For now you should just focus on picking and choosing what you upgrade.  Eventually you will run into an event that will make you several millions of Gil.  Until then, your best bet is just grinding the Gil daily.  There really isn't many stages that are great for getting gold.

Your **FF VI: Mobliz Elite** is likely the best for now.  I can't confirm since I haven't done an exhaustive search, but typically I don't seem to find much Gil in standard Stages.